# "Called but not expected" with mocked open()

Tags: python, python-3.x, mockito

When I try to mock open() with mockito in python, I get the following error:

```
Called but not expected:

    open('/usr/lib/python3.9/__pycache__/doctest.cpython-39.pyc', 'rb')

Stubbed invocations are:

    open('oneWay_matchDict.pkl', 'rb')
```

The line to be mocked looks like this:

```
pkl_file = open('oneWay_matchDict.pkl','rb')
```

While the mock looks like this:

```
pkl_file = mock()
when2(open, 'oneWay_matchDict.pkl', 'rb').thenReturn(pkl_file)
```

How do I ignore other invocations of open?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that was suggested to me (which actually worked) was this:

```
pkl_file = mock()
when2(open, ...).thenCallOriginalImplementation()
when2(open, 'oneWay_matchDict.pkl', 'rb').thenReturn(pkl_file)
```

The first when2() 'binds' (not sure the actual technical term) to all the calls to `open()` before the particular `open()`.

See https://github.com/kaste/mockito-python/issues/75

Answer (score 1):

Mocking builtins function this way won't work.

If you want to mock `open` function you need to redefine a function in the module you're trying to test. After that you'll be able to override it.

Let me give you an example:

```py
# Import the module (not a member) you're testing
from path.to.module import module_under_test

# Later in the test

module_under_test.open = mock()  # redefine `open` function.
pkl_file = mock()
when2(module_under_test.open, 'oneWay_matchDict.pkl', 'rb').thenReturn(pkl_file))
```

Comment: "Mocking builtins function this way won't work." The approved solution works just fine, so you're incorrect.